# How remove double quotes from a string using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

I have a procedure for delete some datas from my mysql table,

My Procedure is like ,

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `callerlog_forlive`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `delete_custom_fields`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_custom_fields`(IN DeletedFields TEXT)
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM `project_custom_fields` WHERE `CustomFieldId` IN (DeletedFields);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and my procedure call be like `call delete_custom_fields("1,2");`

but its not working. I think its because of double quotes in the input (Iam not sure). How to resolve this ???

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_unquote](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote):

`select json_unquote('"1,2"')`

result: `1,2`